# Converting IEnumerable to a List, will the List follow the same order?

Tags: c#, .net

I know the "Order is not guaranteed" with IEnumerable, my question is different, I have an IEnumerable. I used the ToList() method to create the List.

Does the List now follow the same order as the IEnumerable?

IEnumerable.ElementAt(i) == List[i] ??

Comment: "I know the "Order is not guaranteed with IEnumerable" What are you referring to?

Comment: It will follow the order in which the `IEnumerable` enumerated the items when `ToList()` was called. There is no guarantee that `ElementAt` will yield the same element in later calls.

Comment: "Order is not guaranteed" with IEnumerable is correct and also inaccurate. If the IEnumerable object yields values 1, 2, 3, you will get them as 1, 2, 3. IEnumerable, however, doesn't **dictate** or **impose** order on the type, that is up to the type implementing the interface, but getting values through IEnumerable interface from an object does in no way *change* the order of them, you're guaranteed to get the values in the same order the underlying object produced them. And from this it follows that if you consume the IEnumerable into a list with ToList, that list will have that order.

Comment: As for `IEnumerable.ElementAt(i) == List[i]`, that's a bit more tricky, as every time you call `.ElementAt` it will do a new enumeration over the IEnumerable collection. If that collection has a predictable order, then yes, that will match, but if the underlying object produces the values in an unstable order every time you enumerate over it, then that might not necessarily be true if you do a check after producing the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it depends. `IEnumerable` can be basically anything, so a `List<T>` where the order is guaranteed or a database query where it depends on if there is a `OrderBy` or not.
If you are talking about in memory collections then the order is guaranteed if the collection itself guarantees it([`Dictionar<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0#remarks) for example does not).

If you ask if `Enumerable.ElementAt(i)` returns always the same as `list[i]` if `list` is a `List<T>`, then yes, it guarantees it because [the implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,7db56d44563d8761) checks first if the sequence implements `IList<T>`(like arrays or lists) and then uses the index:

```
public static TSource ElementAt<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int index) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null) return list[index];
    if (index < 0) throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("index");
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        while (true) {
            if (!e.MoveNext()) throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("index");
            if (index == 0) return e.Current;
            index--;
        }
    }
}
```

This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=net-5.0) so you can rely on this behavior.

> If the type of source implements `IList<T>`, that implementation is used
> to obtain the element at the specified index. Otherwise, this method
> obtains the specified element.

Comment: `Dictionary` is guaranteed AFAIK (perhaps not documented), it's in order of hash-code and then in insertion order

Comment: @Charlieface: if you add or remove items from the dictionary you get a different order than before. It is documented that "the order in which the items are returned is undefined", so why rely on it?

Comment: Yes suppose you are right, that's what happens if it's re-hashed. I just meant that there is logic to it, and the result will be the same if no changes have happened

Comment: @Charlieface: it means that they are free to change the implementation tomorrow to return a completely different order no matter what logic it used before.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the order is preserved when using `ToList()`